After I updated to 24.04, Firefox won't launch. Why not?
After I updated to 24.04, Firefox won't launch.  Why not?

Does rico's answer or mine help you?

Try updating all Snaps with the command: sudo snap refresh. Then reboot.

Where do I type "sudo snap refresh?"

In the terminal emulator. Just press Ctrl+Alt+t to open a terminal.

Once I knew how to open a terminal and what to type onto it at the same time, Firefox reloaded itself. No reboot was needed. Thank you.
